# Remover mensagens de um interlocutor sem afetar o outro

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou implementando um sistema de mensagens e preciso fazer uma forma de remover as mensagens de um interlocutor sem afetar o outro.

Fulano e Sicrano trocam mensagens:

1. Em um determinado ponto, Fulano remove a conversa, mas Sicrano continua com o histórico completo da conversa.
2. Quando Fulano e Sicrano retomarem o diálogo, Fulano só verá as novas mensagens e Sicrano continua com as mensagens desde o inicio.
3. Naturalmente, as mensagens só podem ser removidas quando ambos removerem a conversa, e quando uma nova mensagem for trocada não haverá mensagens antigas.

Talvez fazendo uma flag individual com o timestamp da ultima remoção da conversa, assim só seriam listadas as mensagens anteriores à data em que foram deletadas tanto por Fulano quanto por Sicrano. Dessa forma seria mais fácil 'ocultar' na caixa de mensagem as que foram removidas por parte de um interlocutor, mas seria mais complicado combinar o ponto em que ambas as partes excluíram as mensagens para de fato dar um `DELETE`.

Answer (score 2):

Eu prefiro partir pela ideia do *timestamp* também, sobre sua dúvida do `DELETE` eu faria algo assim:

1. Um `timestamp` pra cada usuário daquela conversa que será sobrescrito toda vez que clicar em remover.
2. Fulano removeu as mensagems, quando Sicrano remover faria um `DELETE` na tabela de Mensagens passando o `MENOR` timestamp dentre os 2.
3. Por que o `MENOR`? Simples, com base no menor você sabe que ambos **apagaram** até ali, se você pegar o `MAIOR` vai acontecer do outro usuário não ter deletado aquilo ainda.
4. A partir do momento que já removeu uma vez, toda vez que o próximo usuário (*diferente do último que fez a ação*) fizer a remoção então rodará o `DELETE`.

Comment: Segui o mesmo raciocínio, faria um `select` limitando as mensagens pelo *timestamp*, e o `delete` seria via *cron*.

Comment: No caso do `select` tu vai executar de acordo com o `timestamp` de cada um, na hora do `delete` é sempre o menor.

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que você descreve o problema, me parece claro que uma “mensagem” e uma “mensagem no histórico” são entidades independentes. Você tem que fazer um modelo tipo

```
CREATE TABLE Message (
    MessageId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Content TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE UserMessage (
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    MessageId INT NOT NULL,
    SentBy INT NOT NULL,
    DateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId, MessageId),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES User ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (MessageId) REFERENCES Message ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SentBy) REFERENCES User (UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Você rodaria um *garbage collector* regularmente pra apagar as `Message` mais velhas do que um certo tempo.

- Por força de ordem judicial, você tem que grampear a comunicação da Ana: você cria um usuário para a polícia e adiciona um `UserMessage` sempre que houver um `UserMessage` associado à Ana (você pode ter uma tabela de usuários grampeados e fazer isso via um *trigger*, por exemplo).
- No caso de mensagens encaminhadas ou grupos de distribuição, você só precisa armazenar uma cópia da mensagem pra todo mundo que recebeu a mensagem — isso é especialmente conveniente se as pessoas puderem enviar vídeos, imagens, …
- Se só uma mensagem específica for privada — por exemplo, eu acidentalmente mandei uma mensagem íntima destinada à minha namorada pro grupo do futebol — eu posso apagar aquela mensagem sem destruir todo o resto da conversa.

Comment: Eita, não tinha entendido o problema dele como um "grampeamento". Pra mim era um chat normal hahahaha

Comment: Não está no escopo que o @PapaCharlie definiu, mas pode acontecer (logo, pela Lei de Murphy, _**vai**_ acontecer).

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, é um sistema comum de mensagens, mas não quis entrar nessa explicação para fazer a pergunta mais simples - falha minha. O *cron* faria a limpeza do conteúdo marcado para remoção após *X* meses como manda a lei.

Comment: Não compreendi bem o ponto 1. De certa forma a *ordem judicial* esta certa, mas seria necessário apenas manter o log de comunicação entre os usuários. O `delete` é executado apos o termo legal e a *flag* de exibição da mensagem é que muda.

Comment: O ponto é que a manutenção da mensagem e o acesso da polícia usam o mecanismo normal do sistema, sem você precisar implementar um mecanismo a mais.

Comment: A policia não usa o sistema para acompanhar mensagens, nem ninguém com acesso ao sistema. As mensagens são sigilosas e entregues mediante ordem. Não entendi ainda o que seria *acesso da polícia*.